# the braid groups on the sphere

Tags: gr.group-theory, braid-groups

The braid group $B_n(S^2)$ on the sphere possesses a finite element of order which generates a cyclic group $M$ in $B_n(S^2)$. My question is this:
What is the index of $H$ in $B_n (S^2)$?
Same question for the braid group on the projective plane.

Comment: Please use tex for formatting mathematics, and add some background information. Probably "element of finite order" instead of "finite element of order"? Also: are $M$ and $H$ different objects?

Comment: Thank you Sebastian, ok  i would to ask " element of finite order"

Comment: I'm not sure whether your $H$ is the same as your $M$, which is the cyclic group generated by the only nontrivial torsion element of $B_{n}(S^{2})$.  If $n = 2$, then $M$ is all of $B_{2}(S^{2}) \cong \mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$.  Otherwise, $M$ has infinite index in $B_{n}(S^{2})$.

Comment: yes for n=2 it's ok but if n=3 , B_{3}(S²) is also finite and so H is of finite indexe, if n greather than 3, B_{n}(S²) is infinite

Comment: I believe $B_{3}(S^{2}) \cong \langle \beta_{1}, \beta_{2} \ | \ \beta_{1}\beta_{2}\beta_{1} = \beta_{2}\beta_{1}\beta_{2},\ (\beta_{1}\beta_{2})^{6} = 1 \rangle \cong \mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$, which is infinite.

Comment: sorry Jeff, but B₃(S²) has order 12 because     if we set a=σ₁σ₂σ₁ and b=σ₁σ₂
    Then we have B₃(S²)=〈a,b / a²=b³=(ab)² 〉
    So a⁴=b⁶=1
    a²=(ab)² then a=b⁻¹ab⁻¹ and hence σ₁⁴=a⁴=1
    it's similiar that σ₂ is of order 4

Comment: I don't see where you're getting the relation $b^{3} = (ab)^{2}$ above.

Comment: from Newman theorem

Comment: Sorry, you were right that $B_{3}(S^{2})$ has order $12$.  I was forgetting the $\sigma_{2}\sigma_{1}^{2}\sigma_{2} = 1$ relation.

Comment: ah yes here the sphere relation $ \sigma_2 \sigma_1^2 \sigma_2 $ implies $ \sigma_2^{-2}=\sigma_1^2 $. As noted by Nouar Degaichi, $ a^2=(ab)^2 $. Again using the sphere relation we have $ a^2=\sigma_1^2 $ and $ ab=\sigma_2 $. So we can rewrite  $ a^2=(ab)^2 $ as $ \sigma_1^2=\sigma_2^2 $. The pair of equalities  $ \sigma_2^{-2}=\sigma_1^2 $ and  $ \sigma_2^{2}=\sigma_1^2 $ indeed implies $ \sigma_1^4=1=\sigma_2^4 $. Adding in the relation $ b^6=1 $ we can indeed recognize this as a presentation of $ Dic_3 $, the unique nonabelian group of order $ 12 $ with elements of order $ 4 $